Node application with infinite load
I'm watching a tutorial for node.js and using this code
const http = require("http")
const port = 8080

const server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.write("Hello node")
    res.end
})

server.listen(port, function(error){
    if(error){
        console.log("Something went wrong", error)
    }else{
        console.log("Server is listening on port " + port)
    }
})

When running it, I'm getting 
But when I try http://localhost:8080 its loading infinitely.  Anyone know why?

res.end(), it's a function and you have to call it.

yeah that did it thanks, first time using node so had no idea.

@MatthewZ Fwiw, not specific to node, this is general js problem. Accessing a key isn't expected to do anything, unless proven otherwise. This happens too but not often

@EstusFlask computed properties (could) make that a bit muddier of a problem, at least at the call-site.

You can also try following options
Respond as Plain text
const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
    res.end("Hello node");
});

Respond as JSON
const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" });
    const data = { message: "Hello node" };
    res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
});

